# cannot run react app on different machine

Tags: reactjs

I changed my system and got the react project folder into the new system. while running the app, I am getting the following message:

> react@1.0.0 start
> react-scripts start run

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

i added the below code in package.son but still i am getting an error:

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React example starter project",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "loader-utils": "3.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is no `start` script in your `package.json` so you couldn't run it using `npm start` before

Comment: how was your package.json before ?

Comment: Run `npm install` before `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

> Update: For your updated package.json It is most probably not getting "react-scripts". If you reinstall all the dependencies by deleting node_module and install again "yarn" or "npm install" command, it should remove the error. You can also use "yarn add react-scripts".

From the information available in your question, I think your environment isn't set up correctly. Your package.json should look similar to this:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

You will notice in this example there is a portion for "scripts", which has scripts for "start", "build", "test", etc. Your error is telling you that you don't have the `"start"` scripts.

I hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! however, i am getting below error now:


'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't work out. Did you tried the updated portion at top. "yarn add react-scripts" command should solve 'react-scripts' is not recognized issue.

If you can't solve it any other way, even after deleting the node_module and reinstalling with "yarn" or "npm install". 
Then you can create a new react instanse and if that works just copy the src folder from the older one and install all the necessary dependencies manually. Hopefully you will get a solution for your problem.